# Wikipedia-like references without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a blog with annotated references like <sup>[1]</sup> that.

```
   [1]Jake Smith. http://example.com ..............
   [2].............
```

I want it so the [1] in the text is an anchor that links to the [1] in the References. I know I could do this by doing something in the text like `<a href="#ref1">[1]</a>`and then making every list item in the references have an id, , that is, that is,

```
<ol>
    <li id="ref1"></li>
     ...
</ol>
```

But that's a lot of work for me to go through all the blog posts. I'm sure I could make a JavaScript or jQuery function to add this functionality, but then it would not work with JavaScript disabled. So is there some other function I don't know? Like some fancy CSS trick, or should I just use JavaScript to do this?

What are your recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are:

1. A **blog plugin** that detects this in the content and forms the link and adds the related `id` to the appropriate element for you when the HTML is being output
2. A **script** that runs and does the same thing after the HTML has loaded.
3. Manually adding the links by hand.

A blog plugin is your best bet, since surely this is a solved problem (though it would depend on your blogging platform, of course).

CSS is for styling, it can't add links/ids.

In addition, remember that if you are ever going to display multiple blog posts on each page, you will want to add the blog id to the anchor as well.  Instead of `ref1`, you'll want:

```
ref_[blogid]_[refid]
```

Comment: ok yeah, i just learned about the CSS content, but I guess html doesn't get parsed through it?

Comment: @mazlix CSS `content` can add content based on selectors, but 1) yes, [HTML is not parsed](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html), and 2) it can't be based on, or perform logic of any sort, which means it wouldn't benefit you anyway.

Comment: ok, thanks! and thanks for mentioning including `blog[id]`, you probably saved me a headache

Answer (score 3):

You could have the links inline so it displays normally when the user has JavaScript disabled. With JavaScript on, just style it as a Wikipedia reference.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6A8nX/***

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and CSS are the way to go, if you cannot do this on the server side. The following will do what you want:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            ref {
                display:none;
                vertical-align:super;
                font-size:small;
            }

            references {
                display:block;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"></script>

        <script language="javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                $("references").append("<ol>");
                $("ref").each(function(index) {
                    $("references").append("<li><a name=\"ref_"+(index+1)+"\">"+$(this).text()+"</a></li>");
                    $(this).html("[<a href=\"#ref_"+index+"\">"+(index+1)+"</a>]");
                    $(this).css("display", "inline"); // hides references unless the script runs
                });
                $("references").append("</ol>");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is a reference.<ref>http://www.google.com</ref></p>
        <p>This is a another reference.<ref>http://www.yahoo.com</ref></p>

        <references>
        </references>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML. A better solution would be `<div id="references">` and then using `$('#references')` as your selector.

Comment: That is true. I used the made-up `<references>` tag solely to make it more "Wikipedia like" (and so more usable for the blogger). You are perfectly right that it would be better (from a technological perspective at least) to use `<div id="references">` and be standards compliant.

Comment: I agree with Justin to use `<span id="references">` instead, but I like the idea of using something for the references in the text only, and then have jquery generate the reference list.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is for presentation, and does not provide logic. Javascript is the best answer in this case, because it provides the tools and logic you need to accomplish the task.